# How to use NSTrackingArea

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm new to Mac programming and I want to fire events when the cursor enters or exits the main window. I read something about NSTrackingArea but I don't understand exactly what to do.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apple provides documentation and examples for [NSTrackingAreas](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html).

The easiest way to track when a mouse enters or exits a window is by setting a tracking area in the window's contentView. This will however not track the window's toolbar

Just as a quick example, in the custom content view's code:

```
- (void) viewWillMoveToWindow:(NSWindow *)newWindow {
    // Setup a new tracking area when the view is added to the window.
    NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds] options: (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}

- (void) mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    // Mouse entered tracking area.
}

- (void) mouseExited:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
    // Mouse exited tracking area.
}
```

You should also implement NSView's *updateTrackingAreas* method and test the event's tracking area to make sure it is the right one.

Comment: Okay, this will be a noob question, but where do I have to place the code? Where can I find the custom view's code? Do I have to connect an object to the view in Interface Builder like I do when using outlets and actions?

Comment: This code should be placed in a custom UIView subclass. Then the custom UIView should be added as the window's content view. Using Interface Builder, create or select a content view for the window and specify its class, using the Interface Builder inspector panel, to be the class of your custom UIView.

Comment: Pretty sure you need [trackingArea release] at the end of the -viewWillMoveToWindow: method above.

Comment: Using `initWithRect:[self frame]` did not work for me, however `initWithRect:[self bounds]` did.

Comment: As @x3ro mentions, initWithRect:self.bounds is correct, see the docs.  the rect must not exceed the view's bounds and is relative to the view's coordinate space, so bounds is correct and not frame.  Would you like to fix, @MattBierner?

Comment: is there a way to include the toolbar/titlebar? or is that considered a different view to handle?

Answer (score 9):

Answer by [Matt Bierner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306149/matt-bierner) really helped me out; needing to implement `-viewWillMoveToWindow:` method.

I would also add that you will also need to implement this if you want to handle tracking areas when the view is resized:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
   // remove out-of-date tracking areas and add recomputed ones..
}
```

in the custom sub-class, to handle the view's changing geometry; this'll be invoked for you automatically.

Comment: If you wish to not have to recompute the tracking area after a view has been resized, use the **NSTrackingInVisibleRect** option when creating the **NSTrackingArea**.

Comment: @mark your comment is one of the most important notes on this page!